# ¿Como hago para enviar un documento adjunto en formulario junto con otros campos?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, subida-de-archivos

¡Hola! Estoy con un proyecto personal para afianzar mis conocimientos en PHP y tengo un problema del cual no se como salir.
Estoy desarrollando un formulario de consultas con muchos campos input, algún radio y varios checkbox. Quiero añadir la posibilidad de enviar archivos pdf, jpg... y a su vez guardar toda esa información en la base de datos.
Tengo una página index.php que contiene todos los campos englobados en un form de este tipo:
<form method="POST" action="">

Con esta definición me guarda correctamente todos los campos en la base de datos, incluido el nombre del documento que quiero subir a partir del

El problema viene cuando al form le añado "enctype=multipart/form-data", ya que al hacerlo no me da el mensaje de éxito de envío, solo se recarga la página de nuevo y no me guarda nada en la base de datos ni me sube físicamente el archivo al servidor.

En todos los ejemplos que he visto de funcionamiento solo esta el campo file en el form, pero no cuando hay otro tipo de campos.

En resumen, ¿Como puedo hacer para que el input file me funcione con el enctype y no me genere problema con el resto de campos?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya has intentado hacer debug? si se ejecuta el llamado correctamente? has intentado revisar si al menos la ejecucion si pasa por ahi cuando presionas el botón de enviar? has revisado si los demás valores del POST si llegan? seguro pusiste `enctype="multipart/form-data"` correctamente?

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@. Considera editar tu pregunta y agregar el código como texto en lugar de usar screenshots. También te sugiero hacer el recorrido (está en el footer) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad, así ganas medallas, reputación y evitas que te cierren las preguntas.

Comment: ¡Buenos días! Gracias por las indicaciones y consejos, tomo nota. Ya conseguí que me cargue los ficheros. Un saludo.